# How to rigorously define independent clauses?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, commas

Consider the following sentence:

> The independent filmmaker Ira Sachs’s drama “Keep the Lights On,”
>   which opened on Friday, is neither an especially good movie nor an
>   especially bad one, but it is an exemplary one.

(source: http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/movies/2012/09/the-problem-with-the-liberal-cinema.html#ixzz25u38hVsZ ).

I am confused about the comma that precedes "but." Is "It is an exemplary one" an independent clause? The rule of a thumb I use is a can-it-stand-by-itself test; the sentence above sounds kind of awkward by itself, though I guess it could work. If it's not an independent clause, then why the comma?

Comment: "It is an exemplary one" is a complete sentence. It sounds awkward because both its subject and object are references that can't be resolved without context.

Comment: 'Complete' means it has a subject and a verb, and an object if the verb demands it. It doesn't have to stand alone as an idea. That would make it a sentence rather than a clause.

Comment: This is a very basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It is an exemplary one* is an independent clause because it is not subordinate to another clause. That would not be the case if, for example, it was ***even if*** it is an exemplary one. It is not the comma that determines whether a clause is independent or not. The comma, like all punctuation, is a convention used to help the reader. In this case, it is used to show that two clauses, which could in principle be separate, have been joined together.

Answer (score 1):

Any clauses that are conjoined with ***and*** -- or disjoined with ***or*** -- are independent clauses.

***But*** means the same as ***and***, but includes extra information about expectations.

1. *Bill washed the dishes and Mary dried the dishes.*
2. *Bill washed the dishes or Mary washed the dishes.*
3. *Bill washed the dishes but Mary dried the dishes.*

These are all compound sentences with two independent clauses each. In writing, commas are optional before the conjunctions; -- as always, commas [should be written](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/commas.html) only if [they are pronounced](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/comma.html), and not otherwise.